# PhpStorm 10 Hide "Hierarchy Info" At Top Of Editor?

Tags: settings, phpstorm

I just updated to PhpStorm 10 and now a small sticky hierarchy appears indicating my location in the DOM or in a class etc. (changes depending upon context of the open file).

Do you know how to hide this … I like my editor clean!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Appearance`
3. `Show Breadcrumbs` option

**NOTE:** Re-opening editor tab may be required

Comment: You the man. I searched for just about every term, except "breadcrumbs" (which makes perfect sense) … thank you!